# Searching maximum length and IDs of consecutive TRUEs in R

Tags: r, boolean

I am searching a method (without a for-loop) to find the IDs and the length of the maximum consecutive TRUEs in an array. For example

```
foo <- as.numeric(runif(100) > 0.5)
```

gives you 100 shuffled 0 and 1. Now I am searching the longest consecuitive row of 1 and the corresponding IDs in this array. For example

```
foo2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

should lead to

```
max.dur = 8
max.ids = c(6, 13)
```

I try combinations of table, cumsum and which, but cannot find an appropriate way to do this.

Comment: it cannot be done without using a loop. at some point in your algorithm, you will use a for or while loop.

Comment: That's the point. I am asking that, because it is possible to do this with an for-loop running from the end to the start of the array and writing the lengths of consecutive "1" in a new array and cumsum this sequences. My arrays a very long so this is very time consuming, so I think about a vector-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle`

```
foo <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
XX <- rle(foo)
max.dur <- max(XX$lengths)
max.dur
## [1] 8

max.ids <- cumsum(XX$lengths)[XX$lengths == max.dur] - c(max.dur - 1, 0)
max.ids
## [1]  6 13
```

Comment: Thanks, guys! That's nice! In this example 1 has the longest duration. If 0 has the longest duration, you have to search for longest duration where XX == 1.

Comment: @mod_che Then use `max.dur <- max(XX$lengths[XX$values == 1])`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
foo2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)

tmp <- rle(foo2) # calculates the lengths of runs of equal values
idx <- which.max(replace(tmp$length, !tmp$values, -1)) 
    # index of maximum number of consecutive 1s

max.dur <- tmp$lengths[idx]
# [1] 8
max.ids <- c(0, cumsum(tmp$lengths))[c(idx, idx + 1)] + c(1, 0)
# [1]  6 13
```